# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{e} + 2\sqrt[n]{e^2} + \cdots + n\sqrt[n]{e^n}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{e} + 2\sqrt[n]{e^2} + \cdots + n\sqrt[n]{e^n}}{n^2}$$

I can see a pattern in the numerator, but I don't know how to solve this limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint we can write it as

$$ \lim_ {n \to \infty} \sum  _{r=1}^n \frac {r\cdot e^{r/n}}{n^2} $$

now thats limit as a sum convert it to integral with $r/n=x ,1/n=dx $ thus it converts to $$\int _0 ^1 x.e^xdx $$ thus the limit is evaluation of this integral by parts .

Answer (score 4):

This is a Riemann limit:
$$\int_0^1te^tdt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kne^{k/n}$$